# Failing adding function to addEventListener()

Tags: javascript

I try to add event listener function, but for some reason it fails.
See example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>    
        function loaded(){
                document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("click", showPopup());

        }


        function showPopup(){
            alert('hello');
        }


</script>
    </head>
    <body onload="loaded()">        
        <div id="first"> 
            click me !!!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Clicking on the "click me!!!" text do nothing, furthermore showPopup() function fires once.

I deeply apologize for this trivial question, but I am spending too much time to see the mistake.

Thanx a lot

Comment: `("click", showPopup())` should just be `("click", showPopup)`.  You want to pass the *function*, not run it.

Comment: eh... I removed brackets on showPopup(), it runs fine... :-/

Answer (score 1):

You should not execute the function, but pass it:

Instead of this:

```
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("click", showPopup());
```

do:

```
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("click", showPopup);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("click", showPopup);
```

- removed `()` in `showPopup`

`